# Use my device as laser pointer

Tags: applications

I'm not sure if this is possible, but knowing that is possible to use the device as mouse I think this should also be possible: Somehow connect the phone with a PC, then in the place you touch from the phone, in the computer should appear a red dot (or something).

Is there any app for this?? Is it possible?

Comment: You want to use it as an input tablet, essentially, and the red dot is just representing the cursor?

Comment: @MatthewRead yes, thats right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is totally possible, and there are a lot of remote touchmouse apps available on the Android market. Just search remote mouse, touch mouse, etc. That being said, I think that will be even nicer is to have an app that uses the orientation of the device as the cursor position, i.e. it works like a real laser pointer. (That i have not seen yet and I am coding one.)

Comment: will give u an update when i finish the app. (btw, r u using iOS, Linux or windows?)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use a program such as [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) and set the computer's cursor to a red dot, or just use the regular cursor. Teamviewer has a program that runs on the computer, and an app that allows you to control the computer from your phone. I think it would work quite well for what you have in mind.

Comment: Is TeamViewer lightweight? I thought about suggesting RDP or VNC but they're way too heavy for such a simple task.

Comment: @MatthewRead Which end of it? The Android end of it does some stuff to the feedback to make it display cleaner on the device's screen. I don't know how lightweight the computer end is. I've never been around my computer while I was controlling it. I've never noticed any lag from it, though.

Comment: Lag and precision are probably the most important indicators. Can't speak for the OP but I'd be OK with a processor intensive app that didn't have a lot of network overhead and thus didn't lag.

Comment: @MatthewRead There is a bit of lag, I've noticed, but that could just be because my bandwidth at home is abysmal.

Comment: Its a good workaround but I'd really prefer some simpler and lightweight app.